# Multiplication table with nested loop and user input, include # symbol after even numbers

Tags: python-3.x

Trying to learn python..
I'm trying to build a multiplication table that Prompts the user for the size of multiplication table, with a validation loop if number is less than 2 or greater than 10 as invalid.
I Also need a # sign after any even number in the table and odds just have a space.

[What I am trying to achieve:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0eJd.png)

I used the first code to get a similar image as above but without the # sign behind the even numbers.

I used the second one to try and have a table that I can involve user input but I dont know how to include that if the number is < 2 or >10 that its invalid. And I dont know how to include the # sign after even numbers

```
print("\t\t\t\tMultiplication table")`enter code here`
print("     ", end="")
for i in range(1,11):
    print("%6d  "%i, end="") 
print()
print("-----"*17)

for i in range(1,11):
    print("%2d|"%i, end="")

    for j in range(1,11):
        print("%8d"%(i*j), end="")
    print()
```

## working toward user input table

```
for row in range(0, 11):
    for col in range(0, 11):
        num = row * col
        if num < 10:
            empty = "\t"
        else:
            if num <= 100: 
                empty  = "\t" 
        if col == 0:
            if row == 0:
                print("\t", end = '')
            else:
                print("\t", row, end='')
        elif row == 0:
            print("\t", col, end='')
        else:
            print(empty, num, end = '')
    print()
```

[Result of first code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4S8MP.png)

[Result of second code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7H3oT.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your first code was really close. Here is modified code with my comments:

```
def print_mult_table():
    while True:
        a = int(input('Enter rows count: '))  # allows user to enter string and convert to number of rows
        if a < 2 or a > 10:  # invalid number
             print('Invalid rows count')
             continue
        b =  int(input('Enter columns count: '))  # allows user to enter string and convert to number of columns
        if b < 2 or b > 10:  # invalid number
            print('Invalid columns count')
            continue
        break
    print()
    print("\t\t\t\tMultiplication table ({} x {})".format(a, b))  # added table size here
    print("     ", end="")
    for i in range(1, a + 1):  # using of user-defined value instead of hardcoded one
        print("%7d  "%i, end="") 
    print()
    print("-----" * 19)

    for i in range(1, a + 1):  # using of user-defined value instead of hardcoded one
        print("%2d|  "%i, end="")

        for j in range(1, b + 1):  # using of user-defined value instead of hardcoded one
            current_number = i * j
            print("%7d" % (current_number), " " if current_number % 2 else "#", end="")  # added # for even numbers
        print()

print_mult_table()
```

Output:

```
Enter rows count: 10
Enter columns count: 10

                Multiplication table (10 x 10)
           1        2        3        4        5        6        7        8        9       10  
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1|        1        2 #      3        4 #      5        6 #      7        8 #      9       10 #
 2|        2 #      4 #      6 #      8 #     10 #     12 #     14 #     16 #     18 #     20 #
 3|        3        6 #      9       12 #     15       18 #     21       24 #     27       30 #
 4|        4 #      8 #     12 #     16 #     20 #     24 #     28 #     32 #     36 #     40 #
 5|        5       10 #     15       20 #     25       30 #     35       40 #     45       50 #
 6|        6 #     12 #     18 #     24 #     30 #     36 #     42 #     48 #     54 #     60 #
 7|        7       14 #     21       28 #     35       42 #     49       56 #     63       70 #
 8|        8 #     16 #     24 #     32 #     40 #     48 #     56 #     64 #     72 #     80 #
 9|        9       18 #     27       36 #     45       54 #     63       72 #     81       90 #
10|       10 #     20 #     30 #     40 #     50 #     60 #     70 #     80 #     90 #    100 #
```

Comment: print("\t\t\t\tMultiplication table ({} x {})".format(a, b)) I don't quite understand the  ({} x {})".format(a, b)) portion of this string

Comment: `.format` works like `%` that you used `"({} x {})".format(a, b)` means that it will insert `a` and `b` variables values instead of `{}`, like `"%d %d" % (a, b`), but `.format` is recommended in python3

Comment: how do I make it return to the beginning of the code if they put in an invalid number so that they can put in the right number without ending the loop.